# MPAndroidChart line chart stops displaying new data after reaching half way point

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to generate a Line Chart which adds live data from Heart Rate and O2.
The chart populates the data correctly at first, drawing two lines, however when the lines reach the middle of the screen, the chart stops adding new data but continues to scroll until eventually you are left with an empty chart.

I am not sure where i am going wrong, but here is my code. If someone would be able to show me what i have done wrong and how to fix it, i would appreciate it.

```
public class LineGraphFragment extends Fragment {

private LineChart heartRateGraph;


private YAxis yAxis;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_graph_fragment, container, false);

    heartRateGraph = view.findViewById(R.id.heartRateGraph);

    heartRateGraph.setDescription("");

    heartRateGraph.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
    heartRateGraph.setDragEnabled(true);
    heartRateGraph.setScaleEnabled(true);
    heartRateGraph.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    heartRateGraph.setPinchZoom(true);

    heartRateGraph.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack, null));

    LineData data = new LineData();
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    heartRateGraph.setData(data);

    Legend legend = heartRateGraph.getLegend();
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
    legend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    XAxis xAxis = heartRateGraph.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);

    yAxis = heartRateGraph.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yAxis.setAxisMinValue(MainActivity.lowLimitHeartRate - 20);
    yAxis.setAxisMaxValue(200f);
    yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);

    YAxis yAxis2 = heartRateGraph.getAxisRight();
    yAxis2.setEnabled(false);


    return view;
}

public void setOpacityLow(){
    heartRateGraph.setAlpha(0.2f);
}

public void setOpacityNormal(){
    heartRateGraph.setAlpha(1.0f);
}

public void addEntry(int rate){
    LineData data = heartRateGraph.getData();

    if(data != null){
        LineDataSet set;
        set = (LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        if(set == null){
            
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }

        data.addXValue("");
        data.addEntry(new Entry(rate, set.getEntryCount()), 0);

        heartRateGraph.notifyDataSetChanged();

        heartRateGraph.setVisibleXRange(30,30);

        heartRateGraph.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount());
    }
}

public void addO2Entry(int o2){
    LineData o2data = heartRateGraph.getData();

    if(o2data != null){
        LineDataSet set2 = (LineDataSet) o2data.getDataSetByIndex(1);
        if(set2 == null){
            
            set2 = createSet2();
            o2data.addDataSet(set2);
        }

        o2data.addXValue("");
        o2data.addEntry(new Entry(o2, set2.getEntryCount()), 1);

        heartRateGraph.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private LineDataSet createSet(){

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "Heart Rate");
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set.setLineWidth(2f);
    set.setCircleRadius(2f);
    set.setFillAlpha(65);
    set.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244,117,177));
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    return set;
}

private LineDataSet createSet2(){

    LineDataSet set2 = new LineDataSet(null, "O2");
    set2.setDrawCubic(true);
    set2.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
    set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set2.setColor(Color.RED);
    set2.setLineWidth(2f);
    set2.setCircleRadius(2f);
    set2.setFillAlpha(65);
    set2.setFillColor(Color.RED);
    set2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244,117,177));
    return set2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that i was stupidly doubling up on the following code:

data.addXValue("");

by having the line:

O2data.addXValue("");

after  i removed the O2data.addXValue(""); the graph functioned correctly again.